# External Jar is not visible from classes under a package

Tags: java, jar, package

I have an `external.jar` in my maven project running with IntelliJ.
My `class1` cannot resolve my `external.jar` until I remove it out from `package1`.
Could you please suggest me a best practice in order to solve such a problem by keeping the folder structure as below.

```
mvn -v : Apache Maven 3.6.0, Java version: 1.8.0_212
```

```py
Folder Structure:
-src
--test

---java
----package1
-----class1
----package2

---resources
----external.jar

-target
-External Libraries
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955635/how-to-add-local-jar-files-to-a-maven-project.

Answer (score 1):

You keep all your external jars under lib folder.
Refer below link

http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#System_Dependencies

Comment: This link describes `lib` folder _under Java home directory_, not in your project.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Please use "<systemPath>lib/rt.jar</systemPath>" in place of "<systemPath>${java.home}/lib/rt.jar</systemPath>. " so It takes from your project folder where your pom.xml exists.

Answer (score 0):

Steps for adding external `jars` in IntelliJ IDEA as follows.

1. Click File from the toolbar
2. Project Structure (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> +
   <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> on Windows/Linux, <kbd>⌘</kbd> +
   <kbd>;</kbd> on Mac OS X)
3. Select Modules on the left panel
4. Dependencies tab
5. <kbd>+</kbd> → JARs or directories
6. Select a library you want to add and click Add Selected at the
   bottom of the dialog

Please refer [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/library.html#add-library-to-module-dependencies) official document from IntelliJ.

Comment: JAR is already included with this way and for that reason, there is no issue when sourcing class is not placed under a package. My problem occurs when I put my class into a package and try to use my jar.

Comment: What error you are getting? When you move the class to that package did you refactor copied?